# Javascript, Ajax XML update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with update xml file on my server:
Here is xml file called config2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <device>
        <node>1</node>
        <name>Server</name>
        <description>Serwer systemu</description>
        <area>Salon</area>
        <type>Server</type>
    </device>
    <device>
        <node>2</node>
        <name>Computer1</name>
        <description>COmputer1insloon</description>
        <area>Salon</area>
        <type>Switch</type>
    </device>
</config>
```

What i need is to update name in node 2 only.

Here i have JS code:

```
var name2 = "newnamefsefewfwe";

$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "config2.xml",
    data: {name : name2},
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        alert("Done");
    }
});
```

I tried to do anything but its not updating that file properly. 
Also i created a function to find that XML element. But it is GET type ajax and i don't know how to modify that to PUT that into XML file. Here is the function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "config2.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

        $(xml).find('device').each(function () {
            var node = $(this).find('node');

            if (node.text() == 2) {
                var name = $(this).find('name').text();

                alert(name);
            }

        });             
    }
});
```

Comment: You can not directly overwrite the file, not with PUT or any other type. For that you need a server side script that will handle the request and do the update..

Comment: I can overwrite that file. But it look like create new file.

Comment: What if i will assign xml DOM to variable. Then do the change in JS and then USE put to recreate the file ?

Comment: Think about it for a second.. even if your PUT request was possible, all you are sending to the server is a json object containing one property. How would the server know how to take `{name: name2}` and merge it into `config2.xml` properly?

Comment: Furthermore, it's a security risk to let your files be directly edited like that. You need to call server-side code with a POST request, and then let your server side code handle updating the config file.